# Accessing different `pk` values in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

How do I show just a certain `pk` value of my sqlite database in django?

I have a database that has a bunch of entries. I am currently accessing them through a `DetailedView` and they are all showing up nicely on the screen. i have called the entries `post` and i have given them `title` and `body` elements, which are just of type `TextField()`

**home.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in object_list %}
     <div class="post-entry">
         <h2> <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> </h2>
         <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock content %}

What I now want to do is to place the 10th Database entry in the footer of my `Home.html`. So obviously this databases `pk` value is 10. i am just having trouble accessing this 10th value.
I have tried `{{ post.pk.10 }}` but that doesn't work. What am i missing in order to access only the 10th value?

Comment: You should access this in the view and pass it to the template. Templates are for rendering logic, not business logic.

Comment: But nevertheless, accessing by a static primary key looks "fishy". You should see primary keys as "blackbox identifiers". Not as values with a "special meaning".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, however if i am accessing it in my `view.py` is the syntax `{{ post.pk.10 }}` is not correct. i have also tried `{{ post.pk[:10]}}` with no joy either

Comment: no, you fetch it with `post = Post.objects.get(pk=10)`. Why do you expect `post.pk.10` to work?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks.